Unbuntu 22.04 How to launch a .deb app at boot time without asking for password?
authentication dialog box
I'm facing a ridiculous issue: I've build a custom web browser with electron and would like to use it in kiosk mode. After making and installing the .deb package of this app, it can be launched via the this command: pos. In order to make it start automically at boot time, I install a cron job as follow: @reboot pos it works fine but the only issue is that, user need to input password to a prompted dialog box every time the PC restarted or booted.
How can I make it work without the need to input the password ? I remember Ubuntu 20 does not force password input when launching an application at boot time. I realy want to make it work this way. I've even tried to change the app binary owner in vain : sudo chown username /bin/pos any help ?
Notice that I've tried to find solution on net unseccessfully; most of the case are for old version.

"user need to input password to a prompted dialog box every time the PC restarted or booted."  why? what password?

root password and I don't understand why

Ubuntu does not use root. Nor does cron ask for it when you use cron. By the way: don't use cron for this; make it a service. Those you can manipulate with an automatic user and password if needed for your app

I've tried to setup a service with systemd all the days but didn't succed I realize that ubuntu 22 is very unstable with its systemd. Could you tell me why cron is not good ?

cron starts before the desktop is ready so there can be timing problems. systemd lets you order it so it starts when another service is ready. systemd is very stable and very easy to setup. Just pick another one from your system and edit the exec line.

I just remove everything and try to copy and edit an existing cron as you suggest and getting the error message: "You need to be root to perform this action"

A much easier way to build a kiosk: https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk
